# Rotation algorithm in C ?

Tags: c, image, rotation

I want to apply a rotation of an angle alpha on an image but my function does not give me the expected result.
I have to use it for an OCR project.

I used the following structures:

```
struct pixel
{
  int red;
  int blue;
  int green;
  int alpha;
};

struct image_bw
{
  int *img;
  int w;
  int h;
};

struct image_rgb
{
  int h;
  int w;
  struct pixel* img;
};
```

And here is my function:

```
void rotation_tab(int alpha,struct image_bw* img)
{


 int w = img->w;
 int h = img->h;

 float radians = (2*3.1416*alpha)/360;

 float cosine = (float)cos(-radians);
 float sine = (float)sin(-radians);

 float Point1x=(h*sine);
 float Point1y=(h*cosine);
 float Point2x=(w*cosine-h*sine);
 float Point2y=(h*cosine+w*sine);
 float Point3x=(w*cosine);
 float Point3y=(w*sine);

 float minx=fmin(0,fmin(Point1x,fmin(Point2x,Point3x)));
 float miny=fmin(0,fmin(Point1y,fmin(Point2y,Point3y)));
 float maxx=fmax(0,fmax(Point1x,fmax(Point2x,Point3x)));
 float maxy=fmax(0,fmax(Point1y,fmax(Point2y,Point3y)));

 int destX = (int)ceil(fabs(maxx-minx));
 int destY = (int)ceil(fabs(maxy-miny));
 int *tab = malloc((sizeof(int))*destX*destY);

 int midx = w/2;
 int midy = h/2;

 for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
 {
   for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
   {
     int xt = x - midx;
     int yt = y - midy;

     int xs = (int)round((cosine*xt - sine*yt) + midx);
     int ys = (int)round((sine*xt + cosine*yt) + midy);
     if ((xs >= 0) && (xs<w) && (ys>=0) && (ys<h))
     {
       tab[xs+ys*destX] = (img->img)[x+y*w];
     }
   }
 }
 img->w = destX;
 img->h = destY;
 img->img = tab;
}
```

Comment: Can you post expected and actual output?

Comment: I tried it with just a 3 by 3 matrix and a 90 degrees rotation: 
{1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1}
the expected result is:
{0 0 1; 0 1 0; 1 0 0}
but the actual result is:
{0 0 1; 0 -1956132512 32578; 0 1 0}

(the values are not the same each time I execute my program)

Comment: I just tried it with a 3x3 identity matrix and a 360 degreee rotation. It produced a 4x4 matrix

Answer (score 0):

that's going to produce staircases, moire patterns and other and blockyness if you use it on anything with fine detail. you want to use interpolation to mix the pixels nearest the computed coordinate.instead of just rounding.